# Failed to create FSL Python environment in Ubuntu 20.4 shell in Windows 10

Tags: command-line, bash, python, windows-10

I need to use *fslreorient2std* on some images and I'm trying to install [FSL](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki) in an Ubuntu 20.04.3 shell in Windows 10.

I used *python "/mnt/c/Users/user/Downloads/fslinstaller.py"*, which seems to work fine until Stage 2 where it produces this error:

> ...
>
> Stage 2 100%
> ----- ERROR ----- Failed to create FSL Python environment - see /tmp/fslpython1vkK/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log for details
>
> Post install setup failed [OK] Post installation setup complete
> Setting up FSL software... [OK] User profile updated with FSL
> settings, you will need to log out and back in to use the FSL tools.

In fact, when I check the details in "fslpython_miniconda_installer.log" it reads:

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
> https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/repodata.json
>
> Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>
> HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on
> your way.
>
> 'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64'

And indeed even when reopening Ubuntu, FSL commands don't work, for example "fslreorient2std" gives: "/usr/bin/env: 'fslpython': No such file or directory".
I did try many times in the last days, following the instructions for [Ubuntu](http://neuro.debian.net/install_pkg.html?p=fsl-complete), as well as doing the [troubleshooting](https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FslInstallation#Troubleshooting:_commands_missing_after_installation), but the error does not appear intermittent to me. I did not find an answer in stackoverflow as [this question¨](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645818/fsl-installation-stuck-failfailed-to-create-fsl-python-environment) does not have an answer and the files mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125472/issues-with-installing-python-libraries-on-windows-condahttperror-http-000-co) are not in the corresponding folders in my computer.

Any advice will be welcome, sorry if my question is naive, I'm a new user.
Thanks,
best
L

Comment: The first step is right there in your output: `Review /tmp/fslpython1vkK/fslpython_miniconda_installer.log for details`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did check the log and I pasted the relevant details above in my question!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well on FSL 6.0.3 using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. FSL *requires* Python2.7 for proper installation of fslinstaller.py.
See output of python --version. If anything *other* than Python 2.7.x:

```
sudo apt-get remove fsl
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python2.7
cd ~/Downloads [or directory where fslinstaller.py is]
sudo python2.7 fslinstaller.py
```

This allowed me to use the GUI versions of Feat and Melodic, where previously only the command line versions were functional.